# Number of legend entries equals the size of data set

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, legend, handle

I'm plotting many sets of data in a for loop. The number of sets and size of sets don't have any problems plotting. When I try to add a legend, things get interesting. I get a legend, but I only get the first label to show up hundreds of times! I have one data set with 887 points, I get 887 legend entries.[Here is the plot I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whx2E.png)

You can access the .py and .xlsx files here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QCVw2yqIHexNCvgz4QQfJQDGYql1hGW8?usp=sharing

Here is the code that is generating the plot.

```
# Temperature Data plotting 
=================================================
#initialize figure
plt.figure(figsize=(11,8))
Color = 'C'
Marks = '*','o','+','x','s','d','.'
nm = len(Marks)
q = 0 # Marks counter
c = 0 # color counter
for k in range(0,nt):
    style = 'C' + str(c) + Marks[q]
    test = 'T' + str(k)
    plt.plot([t+t_adjust[k]],[Temps[:,k]],style,label=test)
    #, label = 'test'
    c += 1
    if(c==6):
        c = 9
    if(c==10):
        c = 0
        q += 1
    if(k > nt-10):
        q = nm - 1
# Formatting Figure
#names = '1','2','3','4','5'
#name1 = '1'
#pylab.legend([name1])
#from collections import OrderedDict
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
#by_label = OrderedDict(zip(labels, handles))
#plt.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys())      
plt.legend(loc = 'upper right')
plt.show()
# x axis limits, in seconds
plt.xlim(0,60)
plt.xlabel('t (s)')
plt.ylabel('T (deg C)')
FigTitle = (oper_name + '; ' + str(pres_val) + pres_unit + '; d=' +
    str(diam_val) + diam_unit + '; H=' + str(dist_val) + dist_unit)
plt.title(FigTitle)
# End Temperature Data Plotting     
==============================================
```

I have 14 sets of data, with 887 points each. There is clearly more than 14 legend entries. Not sure why its somehow referencing the length of data or something. I found this (code below) to find the handles and labels, but I need them to be assigned the style name for each data set instead of the first style name for the length of data.

```
#from collections import OrderedDict
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
#by_label = OrderedDict(zip(labels, handles))
#plt.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys())
```

Comment: It would be useful to post the piece of code, that is actually showing the error, preferably reproducible. (to help people in helping you)
Sometimes there may be unexpected errors, in actual code, but not in a `representative` code provided. Plus, there is lot of commented out code here. Is that useful for the question?

Comment: I am confused: Your plot shows labels `"hmmm"` but those letters do not even appear in the code. Instead, one would expect to see labels starting with `"T"` followed by some number. I'm sure once you provide a [mcve], i.e. a runnable code that reproduces the undesired behaviour it'll be solvable within some minutes.

Comment: @Tushar, I have added a link for you to download the code and Excel file I am using.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I updated the figure to correctly represent what is happening, I forgot to update that before submitting. And the code can be found at the link to google drive.

Comment: Sorry that's not what I would call [mcve]. But maybe someone else has the bandwidth to download the stuff and look through that lengthy code.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without having a look at the data, but you can always control what goes into the legend manually like so:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0., 2*np.pi, 101, endpoint=True)

lns = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    for j in range(10):
        ln = plt.plot(x, j*np.sin(x/i), label="series i={:d}".format(i))

    lns += ln # note plt.plot returns a list of entities

plt.legend(lns, [l.get_label() for l in lns], loc="best")
plt.show()
```

Comment: so can I put some kind of string series where you have "series i={:d}"?

Comment: Yes, here I just made up an example but you could have labels defined in a separate list with elements matching range(1, 10). If that was the case, you could even replace the [l.get_label() for l in lns] bit in the legend with that list.